# Citrix - Unable to use Skype for Business audio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, citrix, microsoft-lync

I'm having issues with Citrix HDX Media Engine. I'm able to connect to my workstation virtual machine just fine using Citrix Receiver. However HDX Realtime Connector can't connect for some reason. Skype for Business can't find audio device, but when I go to the Windows volume manager, I both see my speakers and microphone detected as Citrix HDX Audio. The funny thing is it used to work just yesterday, but I had to format my drive and install OS from scratch. Now I can't make it work again. Before the format I had Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows if that makes any difference.

I'm using Citrix Receiver 13.4 and HDX Media Engine 2.2.

I've tried with both x64 and x86 version but no success.

Did anyone run into similar issue before?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP - I tried everything above. Finally I checked the version of the HDX Realtime Connecter on the receiver end (from the notification area, right click on 'about'). The receiver was on version 2.2 but my client had the latest version 2.5. I removed version 2.5 on my client and installed version 2.2 to match the receiver. Now Skype can see the audio device. Happy days.

Answer (score 2):

Go to /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/utils/ and run:`sudo ./hdxcheck.sh`

You will get a summary of the HDX pre-reqs and that will also show you what you need to install.  Likely you are missing the `gstreamer0.10-plugins-base` and `gstreamer0.10-tools`.

You can check those two with: `dpkg --status gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-tools | egrep "Package|Version|Status"`

Comment: If that doesnt work, upgrade to 17.10.  Mine stopped working after some update or some package I installed.  Upgraded to 17.10 and without changing any config files it started working again.  You might have the same issue.

Comment: Mine stopped working again, seemed to be related to dns issues with systemd.  Fixed that, then something else broke.  No errors that I can see the issue with or anything to give a hint.

Comment: `dpkg --status` is a command that does not require elevated privileges, so sudo is not necessary to run the specified command.

Comment: @holmb you are right on that, I will edit it.  I was troubleshooting my issues at the time and just kept reusing parts of the previous commands so I didnt even pay attention to that when I copied/pasted

Answer (score 2):

Adding following line to the wfclient.in config file was a simple solution for me.

~/.ICAClient/wfclient.ini

```
[...]
[WFClient]
AllowAudioInput=True
[...]
```

Comment: That worked for me...